# Where is the partition manager in the Vista installation CD?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I have a Dell pc and when I ran the Vista installation disk which came with the machine, there is no obvious reference to the disk manager where you can add/delete partitions.

Can someone please explain how to find this? Is this an issue with the PC vendor or Microsoft?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Where is the partition manager in the Vista installation CD?

[image]

Comment: There it is! Nicely hidden as "Drive options"

Answer (score 0):

You can either go to the command prompt by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> or by clicking "Repair your machine" > "Command Prompt", then type `Diskpart`

Or, if you do setup, one of the first steps is the GUI disk manager which will allow you to configure partitions.

Comment: I ran diskpart to setup a 250gb partition (Got a 1tb hd), and got this error:

No usable free extent could be found. It may be that there is insufficient
free space to create a partition at the specified size and offset. Specify
different size and offset values or don't specify either to create the
maximum sized partition. It may be that the disk is partitioned using the MBR di
sk
partitioning format and the disk contains either 4 primary partitions, (no
more partitions may be created), or 3 primary partitions and one extended
partition, (only logical drives may be created).